# Show progress bar during Wordpress image upload

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity

I created a site on Wordpress using toolset. The site allows users to upload media to posts. One user creates a parent post and other users can contribute to this parent post by creating a child post and uploading media to a custom field within the child post. Right now I am using toolset and gravity forms. The way the interface is currently working when someone is uploading media, is they upload media within a gravity form and it shows a upload progress bar for each file then they click submit and depending on how many files they are uploading, it can take a pretty long time to submit and there’s not a progress bar at this point. This creates the child post and links the child post and media with the parent post.
Is there a way to show progress while it is submitting or a better way to submit these files altogether? You can see and example here: https://crowded.app/public/ and click the plus button.

I have tried adding visual elements to gravity forms but it still doesn’t provide a helpful user interface for the submission progress.